# Pattern matching python, how to work with matrixes in python?

Tags: python

I have a matrix like this

```
matrix = 
   [
     [1,0,0]
     [0,1,0]
     [0,0,0]
   ]
pattern = 
   [
     [1,0]
     [0,1]
   ]
>>>Should output: Pattern found at index 0
```

I need to find if there's a pattern matching with another matrix given in input
The first matrix can be MxN while the matrix given in input must be PxQ where P < M and Q < N.
I've tried to create the sub-matrixes and then match those with the one I was given in input but no luck for me!
Have you got any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy can create those "sub-matrices" for you using the [`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view` method](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html). It takes as arguments the matrix and the shape of the smaller matrix.

Then you just need to use `np.all` to specify that all elements of the matrix need to match for it to count and to collapse the shape `(2,2,2,2)` matrix into shape `(2,2)`.

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
])
pattern = np.array([
    [1, 0],
    [0, 1]
])

print(np.all(np.all(np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(matrix, pattern.shape) == pattern, axis=3), axis=2))
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid libraries, you could write your own sliding windows function:

```
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
]
pattern = [
    [1, 0],
    [0, 1]
]


def sliding_window_view(matrix, window_shape):
    h, w = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
    window_h, window_w = window_shape

    for y in range(h - window_h + 1):
        yield [
            [row[x:x + window_w] for row in matrix[y:y + window_h]]
            for x in range(w - window_w + 1)
        ]


def find_pattern(matrix, pattern):
    sub_matrices_matrix = sliding_window_view(matrix, (len(pattern), len(pattern[0])))
    for sub_matrices_row in sub_matrices_matrix:
        yield [sub_matrix == pattern for sub_matrix in sub_matrices_row]


print(list(find_pattern(matrix, pattern)))
```

This is not particularly efficient, since it creates new lists for every sub-matrix, however it is fairly easy to understand compared to the more optimized alternatives.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! that's very interesting...What if I don't want to use a pre built method?

Comment: @Allen I've added a library-free version

Comment: Thank you very much! Have a nice evening